# How to see all conversions and custom conversion fields? Facebook ad insight api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I'd like to list all the possible conversion types that are listed in the ads manager from the ad insight graph api.

[image]

The conversions from a query like so give me only a small sample set of whats here.
`insights?fields=actions,action_values&time_increment=1`

Potential reasons:

1. They limit what graph api can do
2. They remove conversion types that have no values.
3. They wanted to make it extra confusing. :O

Anyone run into something similar? This is super frustrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. insights are little bit more complicated and messy....
2. Insights api returning only non-zero values.
3. backwards compatibility of api versions and constantly introducing new metric and changing existing ones by request of rapidly changing marketing industry

There is potentially unlimited number of conversions attached to every campaign/ad-set/ad entity.... what you show on your screenshoot are only some of standard events but there are also a custom ones...

Conversions are not only in actions but for example also in conversions...